# How to control import order in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am experiencing the following issue:

`Shimmed Module C depends on Shimmed Module B which depends on Shimmed Module A`.

Shims are loaded trough standard configuration in the `ui5.yaml` file. As they do not follow `UMD`, their inner deps are transparent to UI5.

At the end, `SM A` is dependency of a controller. For successful use however, `SM B` & `SM C` must've been loaded beforehand.

How can I accomplish successful import **with guarantees** of the order?
Parallel imports don't do the trick for me as they may or may not follow the desired order.

Inline scripts / synchronous import calls are also undesired, as they easily violate stricter CSPs.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a bit too abstract for me. Could you post the relevant bits of the yaml file or controller and what is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue using the [sap.ui.loader](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.loader) & [the official docs on AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/CommonConfig.md). Turns out, each shim can define `deps` section, where one can describe the inner dependencies of the packages. Using this, I could define the proper relations between them. Once this was done, the order of import happened automatically.